# Assertions in loop body

Tags: dafny

Why do the two assertions in the loop body not hold and how can they be made valid?

```
method m(a: array<int>, m: int)
modifies a;
requires 1 <= m <= a.Length;
{
    var m: int := a.Length;
    first_element_is_maximal(a, m);
    assert forall k, j: int {:trigger a[(k)-1] >= a[(j)-1]} :: m < k <= a.Length && 1 <= j <= m ==> a[(k)-1] >= a[(j)-1]; 
    ghost var p_m: int;
    while m >= 2
    decreases m;
    invariant 1 <= m <= a.Length;
    {
        first_element_is_maximal(a, m);
        assert forall k: int {:trigger a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1]} :: 1 <= k <= m ==> a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1]; 
        a[(1)-1], a[(m)-1], m, p_m := a[(m)-1], a[(1)-1], m-1, m;
        assert forall k: int {:trigger a[(p_m)-1] >= a[(k)-1]} :: 1 <= k <= p_m ==> a[(p_m)-1] >= a[(k)-1];
    }
}

lemma first_element_is_maximal(a: array<int>, m: int)
requires 1 <= m <= a.Length;
ensures forall k: int {:trigger a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1]} :: 1 <= k <= m ==> a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1];
```

Adding a corresponding invariant to the loop does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to say without seeing more of your problem, my impression of your problem is that you have a sorted descending list and you are iterating through your list for some reason. Your method does not have an ensure clause so it isn't clear what you are trying to verify.

I will suggest a few improvements. You are using a lemma to make assertions about your data but you can do this using require statements and predicates.

```
predicate first_element_is_maximal(a: array<int>, m: int)
requires 1 <= m <= a.Length
reads a
{
  forall k: int {:trigger a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1]} :: 1 <= k <= m ==> a[(1)-1] >= a[(k)-1]
}

method m(a: array<int>, m: int)
modifies a;
requires 1 <= m <= a.Length;
requires first_element_is_maximal(a,m)
{
    var m: int := a.Length;
    assert forall k, j: int {:trigger a[(k)-1] >= a[(j)-1]} :: m < k <= a.Length && 1 <= j <= m ==> a[(k)-1] >= a[(j)-1]; 
    ghost var p_m: int;
    while m >= 2
    decreases m;
    invariant 1 <= m <= a.Length;
    invariant first_element_is_maximal(a, m)
    {

        a[(1)-1], a[(m)-1], m, p_m := a[(m)-1], a[(1)-1], m-1, m;
        assert forall k: int {:trigger a[(p_m)-1] >= a[(k)-1]} :: 1 <= k <= p_m ==> a[(p_m)-1] >= a[(k)-1];
    }
}
```

To describe that the array is sorted I would suggest the following predicate.

```
predicate SortedDesc(a: array<int>) 
   reads a
{
   forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < a.Length ==> a[i] >= a[j]
}
```